# How to nest states in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am developing Angularjs application. I am new to Angularjs. I am facing some issues in Nesting of UI states. My requirement is to develop forgot password page.  Flow will be as below.

```
ForGotPassword
  Step 1: MobileNumber
          DOB
          Submit->If successful then
 Step 2:  OTP
          Verify->If successful then
 Step 3:  New Password
          Confirm Password
          Submit.
```

For the above three steps I want to inject the respective pages in

```
class="container">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
```

This is my main controller.

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
   $stateProvider.state('ForgotPassword', {
        url: '/ForgotPassword',
        templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.html',
        controller: 'ForgotPassword'
    });
});
```

This is my forgotpassword controller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ForgotPassword', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
        $stateProvider
         .state('ResetPassword', {
             url: '/ResetPassword',
             templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ResetPassword.html',
             controller: 'ResetPassword'
         });
        $stateProvider
        .state('OTPVerification', {
            url: '/OTPVerification',
            templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/OTPVerification.html',
            controller: 'OTPVerification'
        });
        $stateProvider
       .state('ChangePassword', {
           url: '/ChangePassword',
           templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ChangePassword.html',
           controller: 'ChangePassword'
       });
    }]);
})();
```

Forgotpassword.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Also i have ResetPassword.html,OTPVerification.html,ChangePassword.html with respective text boxes. I am not sure I am doing it correctly or not? May I get some help here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this for implementing nested states and view using angular ui router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ForgotPassword', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
        $stateProvider
         .state('ForgotPassword.ResetPassword', {
             url: '/ResetPassword',
             templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ResetPassword.html',
             controller: 'ResetPassword'
         });
        $stateProvider
        .state('ForgotPassword.OTPVerification', {
            url: '/OTPVerification',
            templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/OTPVerification.html',
            controller: 'OTPVerification'
        });
        $stateProvider
       .state('ForgotPassword.ChangePassword', {
           url: '/ChangePassword',
           templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ChangePassword.html',
           controller: 'ChangePassword'
       });
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. Whenever i click on forgot password i want to inject ResetPassword.html in <div class="container"><div ui-view></div></div>. May i know how to achieve this?

Comment: You have to give child state name as parent.childStateName

Comment: .state('ForgotPassword.ResetPassword' like this i should use right?

Comment: Thank you. In first line  angular.module('RoslpApp') should i inject ['ui.router']?

Comment: I am not able to inject the view. Please find my plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/0oaCZzKDcUu6CJSY8lWH?p=preview. May i get some help here? Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better if you can make a routes.js and define all states there instead of defining one in mainController and child states in ForgotPassowrdController.

Comment: Yes. It is confusing now. Thanks. Whenever i click on Forgot password tab my forgotpassword.html page loads but i want to load Resetpassword.html page.

Comment: Thank you. In my project when i click on Forgotpassword tab i should invoke ResetPassword.html or Forgotpassword.html page?

Comment: Have you use ui-sref to move to child view??

Comment: I use   <li><a ui-sref="ForgotPassword">{{ 'ForgotPassword' | translate }}</a></li>.

Comment: My problem is Whenever i click on Forgotpassword tab my Forgotpassword.html page loads. In Forgotpassword.html i have <div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>. In this i want to inject Resetpassword.html but this is not happening.

Comment: Why you are writing ui-sref="ForgotPassword", if you wan to move to resetPassword view?? Change it to ui-sref="ForgotPassword.Resetpassword".

Comment: Worked. This is what i looking for. Thanks a lot for helping me.